# Puzzle pieces segmentation with OpenCV

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am looking to solve a half-solved jigsaw puzzle using an OpenCV. in one image I have a half-solved jigsaw puzzle and in the other image, I have missing pieces.

What is the best method to separate missing pieces from the second image and matched them to the half-solved puzzle? (missing pieces are on a white background)

Comment: Best in what sense ?

Comment: Accuracy wise. Time complexity is not an problem.

Comment: Are the pieces of the traditional shape (quadrilateral with one tenon or one mortise per side) ?

Comment: Yes they are traditional shaped. I was thinking of using contour detection on OpenCV. Just stuck on the implication.

Comment: [This](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs231a/prev_projects_2016/computer-vision-solve__1_.pdf) looks interesting.

Comment: @dev_neil Maybe you want to try [connected component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) implemented in [skimage](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_label.html) "*to separate missing pieces from the second image*"

Answer (score 0):

**Ideas:**

You can base the search on the positions of the corners of the pieces. Identify them on the isolated pieces, and inasmuch as this is possible, on the partly solved puzzle.

Consider all free sides on the puzzle and try all pieces in turn. It is easy to align a piece based on two corners. Measure the matching based on 1) shape compatibility and 2) content compatibility along the common edge.

Keep the piece with the best match and continue the process.

For the best chances of success, it is preferable to work first on the most discriminant side among the free ones. This means the one which is the most dissimilar (using the same shape and color criteria) to all others. This involves a form of clustering of the sides. Also prefer locations surrounded by two, three or even four free sides.